# 2D Hash map vs 2D dynamic array

Tags: multidimensional-array, data-structures, hashmap

Let *map* be a 2D hash map (with two keys) and *array* be a 2D dynamic array.

Can we say *map* takes more memory than *array* to store information?
Can we say that *map* is faster than *array* for retrieving information?
Are there other pros and cons using any of these two data structures?

Answer (score 0):

Afraid the best answer is, *"it depends"*.

If you're treating that 2-dimensional array like a spatial partitioning NxM grid, just like the hash table, it can potentially be very sparse (some cells will simply be unoccupied). So both can potentially waste a lot of memory.

Unlike a hash map, we don't have to redundantly store the key pairs into such a 2D structure, so there could be some potential benefits there. However, this is kind of an unfair comparison, as a hash set wouldn't either and we don't necessarily need an associative structure with key/value pairs, only keys.

A hash table is also still a 1-dimensional data structure at the end of the day, as the paired aspect of your key is irrelevant except in the hashing function to map it to a 1-dimensional position.

In practice, I've seen the 2-dimensional partitioning grid can tend to outperform the hash table. This is not a guarantee as there's too many factors involved (including the skill of the implementors), but it may have a slight edge to the hash table in an "average" scenario.

The main reason is because of collisions: a hash table has to map those key pairs into a 1-dimensional index, so it can more easily degrade performance due to more collisions unless your table is very sparse (in which case more memory, fewer cache hits which also degrade performance, etc) or unless you just have a fantastic hash function for these key pairs.

The 2D grid tends to be easier to provide more "stable" performance without skewing and degrading. It faces a worst-case scenario when you have many 2D "points" lying in the same grid cell that theoretically the hash table might resolve to different buckets, but often it's easier to avoid this and/or adapt to this than the hash table which could start receiving a lot of collisions for far less predictable reasons. If you use a 2D grid, however, you generally want to involve list pointers/references with a chaining approach (and possibly with some micro-optimizations to reallocate elements in a cell for spatial locality), since there's not quite as practical of a method of resolving collisions that way.

You do get some more flexibility with the 2D grid as a bonus, like nearest neighbor searches or searches for "points" within a search radius. The searches don't have to be for exact matches.

Though there is a benefit to hash tables that could be quite great in some scenarios. It doesn't require you to understand the range of your keys in advance. With a grid, you have to know in advance that your keys range from `[0,10000]`, e.g. A hash table can deal with `(-inf,+inf)` ranges, so it might be quite useful there for very dynamic scenarios where you can't anticipate anything about the data you insert in advance.